# sistema de licencia en VisualStudio

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2015, windows-installer

Buenas Noches Sres. al final, terminando un proyecto en `VS2015` me gustaría que éste detecte cuando sea instalado en una PC y desactivarlo para evitar la piratería estuve leyendo acerca de Firmar un ensamblado pero cuando lo activo y genero un `.exe` ojo desde `VS2015` se instala pero luego da error de ejecucion, he intentado "probando en mi pc" instalarlo y me doy cuenta que no se crea una carpeta en especifico, ejemplo `"c:/archivo de programas/sistema"` y por ende no veo los archivos especificos del sistema, me gustaria verlos para manipular el `app.conf`  sin tener que volver compilar. Disculpen tantas dudas,
para aclarar necesito ayuda en:

> 1-Licencia para protegerme de la pirateria
>
> 2-encontrar o dejar libre el app.conf para manipular la cadena de conexion fuera de VS2015

para aclarar algo, si me quiero cuidar de la piratería debería solo tener `software originales` e [installshield](http://www.flexerasoftware.com/producer/products/software-installation/installshield-software-installer/) en estos momentos es  inaccesible. muchas gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tiene Razon Dekadence Nakura, es muy dificil hacer esto de manera que no te puedan crackear, posiblemente imposible. Te comento como lo haria yo por si te puede servir de ayuda:

Obligaria al usuario a estar conectado a internet a una web/ftp, etc tuyo en el momento de instalar el software en el equipo, al hacer la instalación se recogeria diversa informacion hardware/fecha etc... y se enviaria encriptada a tu servidor, el en servidor realizara diversas operaciones con esa informacion de tal forma que generaria una especie de Token de validacion.
Al realizar la instalacion se instala tambien una .dll en el equipo que calcula el Token de validacion.

Cuando se ejecuta la aplicación comprueba dicho token en funcion del hardware/fecha, etc , si pasa la funcion de validacion se puede ejecutar, sino dara error.

Esto te puede evitar que te hackeen a corto plazo o que solo alguien que vaya a crackearte de verdad lo consiga, es decir te dara algo de tiempo.
A partir de aqui lo suyo seria que cada semana se hiciese una pequeña actualizacion del programa muy rapida donde solamente se descargaria la aplicacion .exe y la .dll a la que esta apunta ( de esta forma puedes cambiar el nombre de la funcion y la firma obligando a dedicar mas tiempo al cracker a buscarla cada semana).

De esta manera le das al cliente la posibilidad de trabajar en local sin conectarte a internet durante una semana, pero a la vez te garantizas que crackear tu programa sea algo tedioso y que teniendo que hacelo cada semana al cracker no le interese mucho hacerlo y desde luego a los usuarios piratas les saldria mas "barato" comprar el software si este tiene un precio ajustado.

Tu en tu servidor podrias tener ya los .exe .dll para cada actualizacion semanal preparadas para unos cuantos meses sin que sea demasiado tedioso hacerlo ya que con solo cambiar un poco la funcion desbaratarias el crack de la semana anterior.

Comment: Hola @Urko obligar a alguien a tener que estar conectado a Internet? No lo veo. Y si la aplicación no necesita de Internet para estar funcionando? "Evitar" la piratería al 100% no es posible pero sí se puede hacer más difícil el que usen tu programa sin permiso. He visto aplicaciones que necesitan de una llave en un puerto USB con la licencia encriptada (como es algo que distribuyes a tu cliente, te garantizas que sólo él pueda usar tu programa  ya que es mas difícil de hackear al ser un elemento físico a priori). Tu programa puede leer el puerto y si no encuentra esa licencia pues no ejecuta

Comment: @SergioParra Cierto, de hecho un amigo mio en su empresa estan usando algoritmos evolutivos en usbs que entregan a sus clientes.

Comment: @SergioParra perdon, no termine mi comentaria anterior. La solucion que yo proponia queria que fuese sencilla y facil de implementar que al menos hiciese al cracker desistir por aburrimiento. Para solventar el tema de internet que comentas esa .dll que propongo se le podria enviar por mail cada a una cuenta que especifique el cliente de manera que no necesitaria tener conexion a internet. Un saludo.

Comment: hola, claro yo entiendo que  es imposible al 100% evitar la piratería pero al menos complicarles la cuestión un poco. estoy probando de todo un poco y lo de Internet es la mas difícil pero yo soy de Venezuela y aquí no hay muy buena conexión a Internet(depende de la region), realmente los clientes se quejarian muy rápido y la llave encriptada o un `.lic` es la que estoy tratando de hacer pero que se valide desde internet una vez, asi puedo cargar un moden 3G poratil

Comment: activo y  ya no usaria mas internet y llevarme la inf de la tarjeta madre y llevar un registro ejemplo: si intenta activar la misma `.lic` en otra pc que no sea la misma `MAC`, debera comunicarse conmigo se oye(lee)bien? todas las ideas son muy útiles muchas gracias

Answer (score 2):

Realmente no necesitas ni softwares originales ni InstallShield para cuidarte de la piratería, ni tampoco usar librerías o servicios externos.

Debes diseñar tu propio sistema de licencia, pero debo decirte que lamentablemente no existen soluciones 100% eficaces contra el crackeo de tu programa (ni contra ninguno) siempre alguien con conocimientos en ingeniería inversa llegará a crackear tu programa.

Puedes hacer uso tambien de frameworks para facilitar el sistema de licencias como [Portable.Licensing](http://dev.nauck-it.de/projects/portable-licensing) aunque personalmente yo creo que sería más eficaz un sistema de licencia bajo cloud (comprobación de lado servidor), se podría emular tu servidor de licencias, pero ya sería menos factible a la hora de crackearlo y tendrías el control absoluto del mismo de forma remota, pero tendrías que pensar en una solución para usuarios que no dispongan de conexión a Internet (si tu programa no depende de conexión a Internet al 100%).

En resumen, lo ideal es que diseñes un sistema híbrido (licencias locales y comprobación remota) con tus propios métodos, utilizar soluciones generalizadas como el sistema de licencias integrado en Visual Studio sólo haría que el crackeo de tu programa sea más sencillo, ya que estos sistemas ya son conocidos por los desarrolladores que hacen uso de ingeniería inversa.

Trata de diseñar mediante tus propios métodos, un formato encriptado de archivo de licencia así como tu propia estructura de datos de la misma y a su vez un método de comprobación online (en cada inicio por ejemplo), a ser posible no uses dominios para realizar la conexión, usa una (o varias) direcciones IP ya que mucha gente intentará bloquear o emular tu sistema de licencias modificando el archivo host de Windows.